# Marketshare of various cpu types in Android Phones

Tags: android, cpu

*I think this belongs here, as it's about the programming of android phones, but I'm happy to be corrected.*

Does anybody have good data on what the marketshare of various cpu speeds are for android? Eg 20% fast dual cores, 30% ~= 1Ghz Single cores, etc. Not so much exact speeds, but the general bucket that they fall into.

I'm developing an app which doesn't run well on the older armv6 ~=600mhz cpus, which I think are a pretty small market but It'd be nice to have actual data to base that statement off of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[appbrain.com/stats](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-phones) should help you to know which devices are dominant and [android dashboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) tells which android version is. I guess, most of the devices which support (factory-installed) gingerbread are ARMv7 devices as its more adequate to run on such processor. but we shouldn't over rule this fact that ARMv6 can also be upgraded to run gingerbread.

[image]

Comment: Nowadays even less devices has a lower version than Kitkat (4.2), minapi 15.